# While loop counter in PLSQL

Tags: sql, loops, plsql, while-loop

I am writing a piece of plsql code and ran into a problem.

What I am trying to do is count the number of instances in a column where the most recent number and the preceding number are not equal, this will then loop.  For example,

```
4
3
2
1
1
1
0
0
0
```

would return 3, as 4 decreases to 1 in three intervals.

```
4
4
3
2
1 
0 
0
```

would return 0, as 4 does not decrease in the most recent interval.

So far I have written

```
declare
   Counter BINARY_INTEGER :=1;
BEGIN
   while (select YTDOVERDRAFTS from (select YTDOVERDRAFTS
                 from WH_ACCTDEPOSIT
                 where ACCTNBR = xxxxxxxxxx
                 order by effdate desc)) <>
         (select Previous_YTDOVERDRAFTS from (select LAG(YTDOVERDRAFTS,1,0) 
OVER (ORDER BY EFFDATE asc) As Previous_YTDOVERDRAFTS
                 from WH_ACCTDEPOSIT
                 where ACCTNBR = xxxxxxxxxx
                 order by effdate desc))
         Counter := Counter + 1;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

which is giving me this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyLLj.png

does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use a loop.  Use a self join instead.

Comment: The syntax is: `WHILE condition LOOP statements END LOOP;`. I can't see `LOOP` keyword in your code, there is only `END LOOP`. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/while_loop_statement.htm

Comment: can you give me an example of how I would use a self join in this context?

Answer (score 0):

This how a self join would be written.  Putting it in sql fiddle now so you can play around with it:

```
select min(rnb) from (
select * from (
    select YTDOVERDRAFTS, acctnbr acctnbra, effdate, row_number() over (partition by acctnbr order by effdate desc) rna
                     from WH_ACCTDEPOSIT) a
                    left join 
             (select acctnbr acctnbrb, Previous_YTDOVERDRAFTS, row_number() over (partition by acctnbr order by effdate desc) rnb from (select effdate, acctnbr, LAG(YTDOVERDRAFTS,1,0) 
    OVER (ORDER BY EFFDATE asc) As Previous_YTDOVERDRAFTS
                from WH_ACCTDEPOSIT
                ) x
            ) b on a.ACCTNBRa = b.ACCTNBRb and a.rna  = b.rnb        

        ) c
    where ytdoverdrafts -1 <> Previous_YTDOVERDRAFTS
```

SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf436/4

Comment: I'm getting a "missing right parentheses" error following the ")b" and before the "on b.acctnbr"

Comment: Fixed it now with sql fiddle